# Calling pkill to pause a process with subprocess inside a class in python suspends the python script

Tags: python, multithreading, ffmpeg, subprocess

I have a class that contains a "blocking method". Inside that method, I am listening to keys to perform some actions. The action in question is `pkill`. Below I am pasting it:

```
def show_control(self, control):
    """docstring for control"""                                                                                                                           
    if control == True:        
        from mkchromecast.getch import getch, pause

        self.controls_msg()    
        try:                   
            while(True):       
                key = getch()  
                if(key == 'p'):     
                    if self.videoarg == True:
                        print('Pausing Casting Process...')
                        subprocess.call(['pkill', '-STOP', '-f', 'ffmpeg'])
                    ...
```

It turns out that the `ffmpeg` process is paused, but the python script gets suspended?. I don't understand why that is the case. If one creates the same function in a regular script (not inside a class to be clearer) this does not happen. I have tried using `multithreading` and `multiprocessing` modules without success. What am I doing wrong?. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself. The problem was related to the `subprocess` being inside the `try` block. What I did to solve it was to create a new method that contained the `subprocess` launching the  `pkill` command:

```
def show_control(self, control):
"""docstring for control"""                                                                                                                           
if control == True:        
    from mkchromecast.getch import getch, pause

    self.controls_msg()    
    try:                   
        while(True):       
            key = getch()  
            if(key == 'p'):     
                if self.videoarg == True:
                    print('Pausing Casting Process...')
                    action = 'pause'
                    self.ffmpeg_handler(action)
                ...


def ffmpeg_handler(self, action): 
    if action ==  'pause':
        subprocess.call(['pkill', '-STOP', '-f', 'ffmpeg'])
```

See [here](https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast/commit/76e974938ea95da96dfdc4c804aa645cf9b2d478).